# Python Dictionary from text file

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, key

Hello I have a file text that holds a sequence like this:

```
TCA:DateIn,TimeIn,Content,Quantity,Company,TankerName,Country,PortFrom  
26/02/2013,15:00,Natural gas,30000,Linkers, Blue Ice, China,Shanghai
09/03/2013,06:30,Sugar,45000,Navigators,Lady Fish, Netherlands, Rotterdam
```

how can I using dictionary, header name as keys(DateIn,TimeIn...) and the lines below the values display it into something like this, with the columns being separated by tabs rather than by commas:

```
TCA:TankerName Company      Country     DateIn        TimeIn     PortFrom     Content      Quantity
Blue Ice       Linkers      China       26/02/2013    15:00      Shanghai     NaturalGas   30000
Lady Fish      Navigators   Netherlands 09/03/2013    06:30      Rotterdam    Sugar        45000
```

I have tried many thing but that I can't problem is that I am not able to relate key with values. I am currently using python 3.3.1 but if it works using another version no problem

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Python CSV module:

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html

Comment: Just you typed faster than me :)

Comment: Thanks guys for your help I have tried this but having error: with open("File1.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
 spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
 for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
        
SyntaxError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @Lucien: that error is related to the way your python code is indented, rather than to the csv operation you are trying to perform

Comment: Ahhhhh okk okk Thanks Thanks man it works. Sorry but I am new to Python

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started:

```
import csv

with open('/tmp/ships.csv','r') as din:
    scsv=csv.reader(din)
    for i,row in enumerate(scsv):
        if i:
            for type,data in zip(header,row):
                d[type].append(data.strip())
        else:
            header=row
            d={item:[] for item in row}

print(d)
```